# How to handle exceptions if internet connection is lost while performing async task

Tags: android, android-asynctask, crash

Am developing an android app anytime internet connection is lost at the time the app is performing an async task, the app crashes

Comment: can you provide what you did ?

Comment: why do people downvote if its simple for you might be a headache for someone else

Comment: Catch the exception inside your background thread and, if caught, proceed accordingly (e.g. send event to the UI thread to show error)

Comment: @PdeeAs-Diddy add more information, logcat, show your code etc. The most important is the exception from your logcat that crashes your app.

Answer (score 0):

I used volley library in performing the POST and GET requests, My problem has been solved ever since